# Yii PHP file uploader overwriting on update

Tags: php, file-upload, yii

I have a basic form in PHP framework Yii, the action to create works fine, however, when i update the record (for example if i'm not changing the file upload, but another field), it overwrites the file upload and blanks it, can anyone assist me? I've tried all the validation I can think of around the controller items, but no matter what i add it still blanks it on update.

Here's the view code

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('booster.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'company-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
        'method' => 'post',
        'type' => 'horizontal',
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
        )
)); 

echo $form->textFieldGroup($model,'name',array('class'=>'col-md-5','maxlength'=>75));

echo $form->fileFieldGroup($model, 'logo',
                array(
                    'wrapperHtmlOptions' => array(
                            'class' => 'col-md-9',
                    ),
                    'hint' => 'You can only upload jpg, png, gif\'s – max upload filesize is 1.5mb. Square images are advised.<br/>In certain browsers, you can also drag \' drop files into the dropzone.',
                )
        );
         if($model->isNewRecord!='1'){ ?>
        <div class="row">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" style="padding-top: 25px;">Company image</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/portraits/company/'.$model->logo,"logo",array("class"=>"img-polaroid placeholder")); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
         <?php } ?>
```

And this is my actionUpdate function in Controller

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);

        if(isset($_POST['Company']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Company'];

                        $uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'logo');
                        if (is_object($uploadedFile) && get_class($uploadedFile)==='CUploadedFile'){
                            if(!$uploadedFile == null){
                                $rnd = rand(0,9999);

                                $filename_preg1 = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/", '', "{$uploadedFile}");
                                $fileName = "{$rnd}-{$filename_preg1}";  
                                $company = $model->name;
                                $model->logo = $fileName;
                            }

                            if($model->save()){
                                if(!empty($uploadedFile)){
                                    $fullPath = Yii::app()->basePath . '/../images/portraits/company/' . $fileName;
                                    $uploadedFile->saveAs($fullPath);
                                }
                                    $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->company_id));
                            }
                        }
                        if($model->save()){
                            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->company_id));
                        }
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

Can anyone see where i'm going wrong?

**UPDATE**

Thanks SiZE, the code you gave me worked in one form and not in the other, the one it didn't work in has validation in the model rules

```
array('logo', 'file','types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'on'=>'update'),
```

This only works with the allowEmpty param here as it's not a required field, however, with the rule in place in the model, it still blanks the file field regardless, anyone have any more thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

CActiveForm calls `CHtml::activeFileField` method wich generates empty hidden field to correctly work with model's rules.

You can try this:

```
$model=$this->loadModel($id);
$original_logo = $model->logo;
if(isset($_POST['Company'])) {
    $model->attributes = $_POST['Company'];
    $logo = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'logo');
    $model->logo = $logo !== null ? $logo->getName() : $original_logo;
    if ($model->save()) {
        if ($logo !== null) {
            $logo->saveAs(/* specify path with file name here */);
        }
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->company_id));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer SiZE, seems to work well, thanks again